# Drools - Decision table function call from action value cell

Tags: drools

I'm trying to call a getter method from action cell of drools decision table but getting an error:-

`Syntax error on token ")", delete this token`

see the screenshot below of error and the decision table code.

[image: table]

[image: error]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, the issue was in the action declaration i.e. $obj.setCommissionRecieverMsisdn($param); and i just put one extra bracket in after closing parenthesis ($param)); that's why. ;)